# How to get test agent's state and queue length

Tags: automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

does a codedui tests agent exposes an api to get information
about it's status in real time?

if so where can i find details about it and purhapse code examples?

**edit:**

i've found a way to get some information on test agent via command line (link in the comment section),

still would love to know id there's an api to enable other types or actions, specifically restarting the agent

Comment: after some research i've found this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/allendm/archive/2013/11/21/getting-the-status-of-your-test-agents.aspx detailing getting test agent state using command line

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a lot of functionality to be accessed through TestAgentConfig.exe.  I found an [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2010/10/24/test-agent-test-controller-and-mstest-faq.aspx) that goes into some details on the feature.

Specifically, to start or stop the agent: "Start/Stop service - sc \machinename stop vsttagent ; sc \machinename start vsttcontroller. If the agent and controller are in different domain, you can use IP instead of machine name."

Comment: tnx for the effort but the blog is 5 years old and the only part relevant for my question repeats with less details the link i supplied in the comment